# Why is this ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception occurring?

Tags: java, arrays, hash, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to implement a dictionary with a hash table (not using Java's provided hash table classes, but rather made from scratch). Below is the `insert()` method from my Dictionary class, used to insert an element into a linked list contained in the particular array position.

I am running a supplied test program to determine if my Dictionary class works, but I am encountering a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -5980` when reaching a certain point. Included below is the particular test. Why would this exception be coming up? (I can provide more code if needed!)

Insert:

```
public int insert(DictEntry pair) throws DictionaryException {
    String entryConfig = pair.getConfig();
    int found = find(entryConfig);

    if (found != -1) {
        throw new DictionaryException("Pair already in dictionary.");
    }

    int entryPosition = hash(entryConfig);

    if (dict[entryPosition] == null) { //Dictionary.java:54
        LinkedList<DictEntry> list = new LinkedList<DictEntry>();
        dict[entryPosition] = list;
        list.add(pair);
        return 0;
    } else {
        LinkedList<DictEntry> list = dict[entryPosition];
        list.addLast(pair);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The test:

```
    // Test 7: insert 10000 different values into the Dictionary
    // NOTE: Dictionary is of size 9901
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            s = (new Integer(i)).toString();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) s += s;
            collisions += dict.insert(new DictEntry(s,i)); //TestDict.java:69
        }
        System.out.println("   Test 7 succeeded");
    } catch (DictionaryException e) {
        System.out.println("***Test 7 failed");
    }
```

Exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -5980
    at Dictionary.insert(Dictionary.java:54)
    at TestDict.main(TestDict.java:69)
```

Hash function:

```
private int hash(String config) {
int expBase = 41;
int exp;
int ASCIIChar;
int hashedConfig = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < config.length(); i++) {
        ASCIIChar = (int)config.charAt(i);
        exp = (int)Math.pow(expBase, i);
        hashedConfig = hashedConfig + (ASCIIChar * exp);
    }

    hashedConfig = hashedConfig % dictSize;
    return hashedConfig;
}
```

Comment: please also post your `hash` function

Comment: please assert that your `entryPosition >= 0 && entryPosition < dict.len`

Comment: It sounds like the problem is simply that `hash()` doesn't do what it should - in particular, it's giving you a negative number. If it's meant to give a value in the range `[0...dict.length)` then it's clearly broken.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the hash function to the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
exp = (int)Math.pow(expBase, i);
hashedConfig = hashedConfig + (ASCIIChar * exp);
```

will overflow integer range, therefore generate negative numbers. Add a `Math.abs` before returning hashedConfig.

You probably should do an analysis how this affects the distribution of your hash function.

Answer (score 0):

Right - as suspected, the problem is with `hash()`. This:

```
hashedConfig = hashedConfig % dictSize;
```

... doesn't guarantee that it will be positive. If it's negative to start with, you'll still get a negative number. You could use:

```
hashedConfig = Math.abs(hashedConfig % dictSize);
```

or:

```
hashedConfig = hashedConfig % dictSize;
if (hashedConfig < 0) {
    hashedConfig += dictSize;
}
```

Both will get you values in the right range, but you *may* find the latter is more uniform.

Note that your hashing code is also very inefficient. It's not at all clear why you're not using `String.hashCode()` to start with. (You'd still need to convert the arbitrary 32-bit integer into a value in the range of array elements, but at least the hashing itself would be faster.)

Comment: I hate java for not having an unsigned integer.